# How to integrate eSewa payment gateway for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to integrate `eSewa` payment gateway into my app. As such I have gone through several blogs but did not found it helpful. I could not found pod files also. if I go with SDK then I will get compiler 5.1 error?

Comment: You need to go with its SDK there is no pod present for that

Comment: when i use SDK i got compiler error,  i'm using Xcode 11.2 there i'm getting swift 3.1 not support in 5.2.1 compiler

Comment: You need to change your swift version for that particular SDK is concerned.

Comment: i tried but im adding as a frameWork i couldnt find this framework in target ,

Comment: i used SDK only but i got error : "Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2"

Answer (score 0):

There is no pod for eSewa. You have to download the SDK as zip, drag and drop it on your project as it says on their documentation. 
[iOS Documentation](https://developer.esewa.com.np/#/ios?id=integration)

Comment: I followed this document only, there i have used xcode 10.2 , swift 5.2 appstore/device sdk framework but i got error , while import the file. error : "Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2"